# HTML create table

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble with getting table to look like I need.

I need table like this

[image]

But what i keep gettng is that ether the text of sundmused ja hadaabi are overlapping or thevahetused cell gets too wide so the alignment of thext gets weird. Can someone help me to create a table like this.

Comment: Show us what you've done so far and we help you!

Comment: Provide code samples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have too small table, you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to add `...` when there is not enough space for text.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 30%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100%;
}
table:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
}
table td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.important {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">vahetused</td>
    <td>sundmused</td>
    <td>hadaabid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="important" colspan="3">01.01.2017.00:00-02.01.2017.00:00</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kokku</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">vahetused</td>
    <td>sundmused</td>
    <td>hadaabid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="important" colspan="3">01.01.2017.00:00-02.01.2017.00:00</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kokku</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">vahetused</td>
    <td>sundmused</td>
    <td>hadaabid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="important" colspan="3">01.01.2017.00:00-02.01.2017.00:00</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kokku</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks your second table helped me :D

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspiciously like an assignment! But anyway:

I suspect your problem is that the first two cells 'span' three columns in the bottom row, and they don't do this automatically. Adding `colspan="3"` to the cells gives the result as below, which is guess is what you need.

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">vahetused</td>
    <td>sundmused</td>
    <td>hadaabid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">01.01.2017.00:00 - 02.01.2017 00:00</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kokku</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Dont worry, not for school. For work. I had to re-style entire page because one of our .CSS broke most of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Add your style to this code (padding, margin and color)

```
<table border style='text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse'>
  <tr>
    <td COLSPAN=3>vahetused</td>
    <td>sundmused</td>
    <td>hadaabid</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td COLSPAN=3>01.01.2017.00:00 - 02.01.2017.00:00</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Kokku</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td> </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```